# Is 18.04.1 compatible with my Gemini Lake laptop?

Tags: laptop, intel, mesa, 18.10

I'm getting a Lenovo V130-15IGM 81HL002VGE with a N5000 Gemini Lake SoC. I'm inclined to go with LTS but does 18.04.1 come with a new enough version of MESA?

Also do you think I should go with 18.10 because of improved memory usage? The laptop comes with 4GB which is fine for browsing and office work I guess.

Comment: Why don't you tell us? Ubuntu is free so try it.  It will only take up some of your time. Nothing else.

Comment: Someone in the know could just tell me if 18.04.1 is ready for Gemini Lake and save me some time.

Comment: But that would suggest every system and every user is the same. Maybe some software does not work that you think is important and others just ignore. Your experience with your system is important for only you ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry but to me that reads like every compatibility related question is pointless because you can always just check if it works or not.

Comment: Correct. We do not support hardware recommendations for the same reason: if it does not work someone needs to file a bugreport on it so it can be fixed/added to the package it belongs to. The "does it work" part also depend on how well you understand Linux in general. There is a very simple thing to do: find out the components and check those online. Regarding NICs: intel always good. nvidia/amd gpu does not really matter. both are supported.